# Burninate [underlying] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I was reviewing some questions that use the [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implementation) when I noticed the existence of the [underlying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underlying).

I really cannot imagine any situation where it would be useful. It is simply too general to have any meaning and I don't know of any technical usage that might justify its existence.

It is related to some other tags which would probably be more appropriate for most questions, for example [data-structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-structures) for questions about implementation of object X in language Y.

There are about a dozen such questions and I already cleaned 2-3 of them, but then I thought that before continuing it would probably be better to ask here on meta whether its removal is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Makes sense. Would be like tagging a question `broken` or `obvious`

Comment: Seems like the underlying tag still exists, but now has 0 users and followers. Has it been regenerated *already*?

Comment: The empty tag reaper only runs once a day.  I've put `underlying` on my list of **252** tags I keep dead.